# html2pdf with Django

Tags: django, pdf-generation

I'm trying to generate PDF file from html rendering
I use the following class to generate the HTML

**Views.py**

```
class ReportList(ListView):
model = Reports
template_name = 'myreports.html' 
context_object_name = 'reports'  
def get_context_data(self, *args,**kwargs):
    context = super(ReportListView, self).get_context_data(*args,**kwargs)
    context['reports'] = Reports.objects.all().values('id','idsys','time','item','customer').filter(id =self.kwargs['id'],.... )
    return context
```

**urls.py**

```
    url(r'^reports/(?P<id>\d+).../$', views.ReportList.as_view(), name = 'myreports'),
```

I haven't idea of generate the pdf (by button link)
I tested reportlab and wkhtmltopdf without succes!!

Do you have any suggestions please?

I found django-easy-pdf too, I think that the following class could solve my question:

**views.py**

```
class HelloPDFView(PDFTemplateView):
model = Reports
template_name = 'reports.html' 
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    return super(HelloPDFView, self).get_context_data(
        pagesize='A4',
        title='Pdf - Title!',
        **kwargs
    )
```

but unfortunately I'm not able how use it with my Reportlist class aboove, I need first generate reports.html then myreport.pdf

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^myreports.pdf$', views.HelloPDFView.as_view())
```

Furthermore reports.html contains static files and trans functions

Comment: You can follow this [link](https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/html-template-to-pdf-in-django/),

Comment: @Lemayzeur thank you!! I'm new with Django, I found django-esy-pdf and I think that is more simple than others (I edited the post for the purpose)but I've not idea how merge it with my Reportlist class

Answer (score 0):

Full disclosure - I run [Api2Pdf.com](http://www.api2pdf.com) - it's a wrapper for popular pdf rendering engines like wkhtmltopdf and headless chrome. Both of these are great libraries but getting them to work in your environments can be a hassle.

I wrote a python library that you can use [here](https://github.com/Api2Pdf/api2pdf.python).

In your case, you would do something like:

```
from api2pdf import Api2Pdf

html_template = '<p>Replace this with your report html</p>'
a2p = Api2Pdf('Your-Api-Key')
pdf_options = {
    'pageSize': 'A4',
    'title': 'Pdf - Title!'
}
api_response = a2p.WkHtmlToPdf.convert_from_html(html_template, inline_pdf=True, **pdf_options)
url_to_report = api_response.result['pdf'] 
# redirect the user to url_to_report - which is a link to the PDF
```

Hope this helps